# errors solving SQL challenge: crew members who have a different role in new_database than they do in old_database AND who are still employed

Tags: sql, left-join, full-join

I am trying to solve a challenge "Identify" in Lost at SQL:

> "start_dates". This dataset provides you with valuable information about the employees, including their ID number, date of birth (DOB), employment start date, and their current employment status. It seems like a promising source of information that can help you piece together the puzzle.
>
> "old_database". This database contains outdated information about the employees and their previous occupations. While it may not be as up-to-date as you would like, it could still provide some valuable insights into the history of the employees and their past roles.
>
> "new_database". This dataset appears to be more current, containing updated information about the employees and their current employment status. It seems like a goldmine of up-to-date data that could potentially fill in the gaps left by the old_database.
>
> START_DATES -> id_number , date_of_birth , employment_start_date , employed_or_departed
>
> NEW_DATABASE -> id_number , full_name , date_of_birth , occupation
>
> OLD_DATABASE -> first_name , last_name , id_number , date_of_birth , occupation

> Get a table with the columns Full_Name, employment_start_date, latest_occupation, and previous_occupation. It should be filtered to just crew members who have a different role in new_database than they do in old_database AND who are still employed.

I tried

```
SELECT full_name AS Full_Name, a.occupation AS latest_occupation, b.occupation AS previous_occupation, employment_start_date
FROM new_database 
FULL OUTER JOIN old_database b ON b.occupation <> a.occupation
FULL OUTTER start_dates c ON a.id_number = c.id_number
WHERE employed_or_departed = 'Employed'
```

This gives me a list of the same names repeating many time with all the different roles. But it is not the right answer.

I also tried

```
SELECT full_name AS Full_Name, a.occupation AS latest_occupation, b.occupation AS previous_occupation, employment_start_date
FROM new_database 
FULL OUTER JOIN old_database b ON a.id_number = b.id_number
FULL OUTTER start_dates c ON a.id_number = c.id_number
WHERE employed_or_departed = 'Employed' AND a.occupation<>b.occupation
```

What gets the right answer?

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you supply sample data, actual output, and expected output?

Comment: THE first option gives  'no result' in all columns. The second option gives
'There are 502 incorrect rows in the result'  it would give a list of the same names  for every time it had changed occupation: 'John Smith Captain  First Mate  2019-12-07,
John Smith Captain Engineer          2019-12-07,
John Smith Captain Deckhand 2019-12-07.

Comment: For starters you are using a. alias for new_database, but you don't define it, e.g `FROM new _database a`  P.S.  It makes things clearer if you use more meaningful aliases, like the answer from User12345 below.   And as requested already, and asked again, show sample data.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: FULL JOIN ON returns INNER JOIN ON rows UNION ALL unmatched left & right table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN ON you want as part of an OUTER JOIN ON. After a FULL JOIN ON a WHERE, INNER JOIN or HAVING requiring some column(s) of the right/left/2 [sic] table(s) to be not NULL removes rows NULL-extended for columns of such table(s), ie leaves only RIGHT/LEFT/INNER [sic] JOIN ON rows, ie "turns FULL JOIN into RIGHT/LEFT/INNER JOIN". PS This is a faq. But one must pin down via a [mre] & write many clear, concise & precise phrasings of one's question to search reasonably.

Comment: A [mre] includes: cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) PS  [Is there any rule of thumb to construct SQL query from a human-readable description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you use `FULL OUTER JOIN` in this case when you can simply use `INNER JOIN` here. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    nd.full_name AS Full_Name,
    sd.employment_start_date,
    nd.occupation AS latest_occupation,
    od.occupation AS previous_occupation
FROM
    start_dates sd
INNER JOIN
    new_database nd ON sd.id_number = nd.id_number
INNER JOIN
    old_database od ON nd.id_number = od.id_number
WHERE
    sd.employed_or_departed = 'Employed'
    AND nd.occupation <> od.occupation;
```

You can check the sample fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z2tuKlVF)

Comment: Please share your sample data